# Why does qualified name lookup find an unscoped enumerator?

Tags: c++, enums

Section, `N4296::7.2/11 [dcl.enum]`:

> Each enum-name and each unscoped enumerator is declared in the scope
>   that immediately contains the enum-specifier. Each scoped enumerator
>   is declared in the scope of the enumeration. These names obey the
>   scope rules defined for all names in (3.3) and (3.4).

So it means, that unscoped enumerators aren't declared in the enumeration scope, but declared in the scope, immediately containing their. So, why does the qualified-name-lookup find such enumerators?

```
#include <iostream>

enum A{ x = -2, y = 2 };

int a = x;

int b = A::y; //OK, but it's not clear why?

int main()
{ 
    std::cout << b << std::endl; 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab7ce1a70e273a8c)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a special rule in the standard.

> A name prefixed by a *nested-name-specifier* that nominates an enumeration type shall represent an enumerator of that enumeration.

(C++11 [basic.lookup.qual]/5; same in N4296)